# To what extent does the location of a conference impact the number of submissions?

Tags: conference, reference-request, travel

Some conferences take place in locations that are considered to be more attractive than others to most people (e.g. [UIST 2014](http://www.acm.org/uist/uist2014/) @ Hawaii). Some can be more easily accessible than others. Etc.

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at the impact of the location of a conference with regard to the number of paper/poster/etc. submissions?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/is-it-fair-to-organize-conferences-in-beautiful-tourist-places/

Comment: Are you only interested in submissions or would number of accepted be relevant? What about number of attendees?

Comment: @StrongBad That would be interesting too. I did not mention them as I was afraid those two numbers might sometimes be influenced by the size of the venue, but I'm not sure how often a conference sells out (never happened to the ones I went to) and I don't know what are the criteria that determine the number of accepted papers.

Comment: Sid Harris did a cartoon on this--of course--a professor is standing in a travel agent's office saying something like *"I'm looking for a conference near a beach or mountinain..."*.

Comment: For [ARO's](http://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.aro.org/resource/resmgr/Newsletters/The40thAnniversaryofARO.pdf) February meeting, the Baltimore meeting was better attended than the Denver meeting, and from what I remember Baltimore also beats Daytona, New Orleans, Phoenix, Anaheim, and San Diego.

Comment: It is compete coincidence that in my gf's field the big conferences are in New Orleans, San Diego, and Salt Lake City during skiing season.

Comment: @StrongBad a factor to your observation is that the East Coast has a higher density of universities than the rest of the country. It is also more practical and cheaper to travel to from Europe.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a specific study on this matter, but I can at least offer one piece of data.  There is a conference that I frequently attend which has a community mainly composed of Europeans and Americans.  As such, it switches back and forth between the two continents each years.  The American contingent is smaller than the European, however, and there has been a clear pattern of American years having lower attendance than European years.  This has been attributed, on the basis of a lot of anecdotes, both to the difference in travel expenses and also to restrictions on the use of travel funds by some agencies on each side of the Atlantic.

Comment: The question (and more generally, questions tagged [tag:reference-request]) specifically asks for a supporting document or citation (per reference-request tag excerpt)